# How can i change the color of a tile which was clicked of a treemap in highcharts using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-hooks, react-highcharts

I am using Tree map chart from High-chart library, but I am facing an issue with the changing the color of the active tile or the tile which was clicked, I tried from my end by updating the color of the current which was clicked, but it didn't work as it was updating the tile which was clicked and I don't want that I want the colors to change only when i click on a sports tile and after clicking on other sport it(the previous sport)  should go back to its actual color

```html
<iframe src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-thompson-7fsijn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark"
     style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;"
     title="busy-thompson-7fsijn"
     allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; hid; microphone; midi; payment; usb; vr; xr-spatial-tracking"
     sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
   ></iframe>
```

Below is the link to my code, I hope you guys could help me with this thanks in advance

https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-thompson-7fsijn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-thompson-7fsijn?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to avoid unnecessary chart redraw memoize your options or keep them in a state. To change color of the clicked point and restore the original one, you can save the current color on a series and use `point.update` method to change/restore. For example:

```
click: function(event) {
  const point = event.point;
  const prevClickedPoint = point.series.clickedPoint;

  if (prevClickedPoint) {
    prevClickedPoint.update({ color: prevClickedPoint.orgColor }, false);
  }

  point.orgColor = point.color;
  point.series.clickedPoint = point;

  point.update({ color: "red" }, false);
  point.series.chart.redraw();

  if (point.node.childrenTotal === 0) {
    var category = point.node.name;

    setSports(category);
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-wave-ibtc2-ibtc2r?file=/src/App.js

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Comment: Hi, That worked and it was great but now I realize that the color change can become extreme and do not look good, is there any way that we highlight just the selected part and dim other tiles. But again thanks for the help

Comment: Hi @Sagar Jha, I am glad that I could help. As to your question - you can use the same technique and only modify the color, for example by using `tweenTo` method (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Color#tweenTo). Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-wave-ib-ku336y?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

set a class name in title and give a style to change the colour

Comment: Please add a sample of your response using the question snippet